# react navigation I can't send the parameters to the previous page when I came to this page from

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v6

have a good day
I use `react navigation v6`
I have a problem in a special mode with sending `params`
I have 3 screens like this

`screenA screenB screenC`

I can't send the `params` to the previous screen when I came to this page from the previous screen and now I want to navigate and send new `params` to the previous screen.

When it goes from `screenA` to `screenB` and then to `screenC`, the problem starts from now on
Now the navigation order is like this

`screenA -> screenB -> screenC`

Now, click on a button from `screenC` and go to `screenB`, it does not send any parameters from `C` to `B`, but it navigates as if it is `going back`, which should not be like this.

But if the user goes from `screenA` to `screenC` and from there to `screenB`, everything is correct and the parameters are sent from C to B correctly.

`screenA -> screenC -> screenB`

while all 90% follow this path

`screenA -> screenB -> screenC -> screenB -> screenC -> screenB ...`

Can someone guide me, what is happening and what should I do?

Comment: the button you used in screen C to navigate to screen B has props in it right? I mean you haven't used goBack()?

Comment: Please, share the relevant snippets of your current code or otherwise we can just make assumptions.

Comment: @vatsalsoni No, I don't use go back, all my routes have params
I think that screenB is not updated and cannot get the new parameters.
Let me test something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution solved my problem with mounted /unmounted on screenB
like this

```
export default class getaway extends PureComponent {

    state={}

    _Mounted = false

    componentDidMount(){
        this._Mounted = true
        this._Mounted ? 'your code' : null
    }   
    componentWillUnmount(){
        this._Mounted = false
    } 
    render() {
        return (
        <View>
            <Text>getaway</Text>
        </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always push a new screen with new params. I'll attach the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/#navigate-to-a-route-multiple-times) to you to understand.

Comment: I don't use push (navigation.push) i use in every routes from navigation.navigate.
Do you mean that I should use push?
If push was not for not being able to use goBack()

Comment: navigation.push can be used in different use cases. Since in your use case the user can can navigate from screenA -> screenB -> ScreenC -> screenB (with new params). You can use navigation.push here. But when you go back it will remove each stack by stack. go back screens (screenB  ->  ScreenC -> screenB -> screenA)

Comment: ooowww so let me try push

Comment: Your explanation was very good and helped me, but the solution to my problem was solved with mounted / unmounted